# Motorcycle: Fuel Injection light comes on after 5 mins of riding

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, kawasaki, fuel-injection

I've bought a brand new bike and have had it for about 2 months. Later this week I noticed that after about 5 mins of riding the Fuel Injection light comes back on. I stop the bike, turn the ignition off and turn it back on letting the fuel rails charge again and it seems to be good.

I noticed a little decrease in power when the light is on.

Also, when the fuel rail charges in makes a kind of gurgling noise rather then an electric purr with other bikes I've ridden.

Could this be the fuel pump acting up?

(PS: bike is a 2012 Kawasaki W800 and I run it on 95 octane premium. Bike has been successfully broken in.)

Comment: The decrease in power is probably from the engine going into some kind of limp mode when the error code is thrown. The FI light could be caused by a number of things though. What's the warranty like in Australia?

Comment: 2 Years. Should still be good to take in

Comment: This question has been open for two years and has gone unanswered.  I'm wondering if you have resolved the issue, if you have could you put the answer to the problem in the form of an answer and award yourself the answer?  Wow...horrible sentence...sorry for that.  but...could you, I'm interested in knowing what the issue was and it will improve the site to have an answer to have the knowledge for future users.  Thanks and cheers!

Comment: @MeltingDog    check the answer, it should work for you to get the data you need to troubleshoot your FI issue.

Comment: @MeltingDog I stumbled on your post by chance, maybe it is resolved. I bought the same bike at the same time and there was a safety recall to change the fuel pump, maybe yours is concerned : https://www.kawasaki.com/OwnerSupport/SafetyRecall

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like a fuel pump, or maybe a clogged filter. If the pump got hot after a few minutes and failed to deliver enough fuel to the rails, the mixture would go lean, the O2 sensor would see that it was lean and would adjust the mixture to keep bad things from happening, hence the decrease in power.

Answer (score 3):

## Need the FI Error Codes First

There multiple possible answers as to why your FI light is on but this is a bit of a guessing game unless you pull codes using the following procedure.  This is a workaround from using the official Kawasaki dealer tool to get your fuel injection related error codes.  Once you have collected the error codes you can now begin to troubleshoot your issue.

**Here is the procedure to get Kawasaki fuel injection system error codes**

**Step 1**
Pull off your seat and near the battery negative terminal there will be a self diagnosis lead coming out of a connector.  The wire is yellow.  It looks like this.

[image]

**Step 2**
Get a wire, one with alligator clips on either side is what I use.  Makes things a bit easier.

Attach the alligator clip to the yellow wire.

**Step 3**
Turn the ignition switch to the 'ON' position and wait a few seconds for the start procedure to complete.

**Step 4**
Attach the lead to the batter negative (ground)

**Step 5**
Watch your FI light.  It will begin to blink long and short flashes.

**Step 6**
You will now interpret the flashes into a numerical value using the following table.

[image]

**Interpreting Error Codes**

The FI light will be flashing long and short blinks.

The long blinks represent 10 through 90.

The short blinks represent 1-9

If you get three long flashes followed by 4 short the error code would 34 and you can reference on the table.